# Dynamically display welcome string in "Your logo here"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

What I am trying to do is to dynamically display welcome string of the company name based on url the area of "Your logo here" in MVC 4 Internet applcation.
So if I am in http://aaa.com I wanna to say `welcome to aaa`

What I have done is to replace

```
<p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("your logo here", "Index", "Home")</p>
```

to

```
@Html.Partial("_Company")
```

and in the _Company view I do `@Html.RenderAction( "Company", "Home")`
and in the HomeController I use

```
public ActionResult HospitalInfo()
        {
           var url = GetUrlMethod();
           return PartialView("_Company ", new { name = url });
        }
```

Can anyone please let me know if my idea is correct or not ? or can you help me to improve the method. Currently, my code does not work at all...

Comment: How did you implement GetUrlMethod?

Comment: Also you are sending an anonymous object as a model. Try creating a model type.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only interested in a string, you don't need to spin up a separate partial view with its own controller action.  Just create a helper function, manipulate the URL in there, and then call the function directly from your View.

.cs:

```
public static string GetCustomWelcomeString()
{
    string customString;

    // use System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url here to do the cool stuff

    return customString;
}
```

.cshtml:

```
<p class="site-title">@MyClass.GetCustomWelcomeString()</p>
```

For a more architecturally clean solution, consider pre-calculating this title in the main controller action and returning it as a model field, so the view can consume it directly using @Model.CustomWelcomeString or something like that..

Answer (score 0):

Try using the request object:

```
<p>Host is @Request.Url.Host</p>
```

You can split the URL however you want, but it doesn't need to go to the controller to get it

Answer (score 0):

I ended up to use @ViewBag.CompanyName and created a base controller which all other controllers inherated from. And create a action method in which passing the company name string into @ViewBag.CompanyName.

So far so good.